# error in sending confirmation email

Tags: php, oop, smtp, localhost

I'm creating a user registration form and after they fill in all the information and submit the form all of the data goes in my database table. After a successful registration A confirmation email is sent to the users email address which is supplied by the user in the registration form. But the email is not sending.I am getting the error message shown below:

```
    Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port        
     25,  verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in 
  php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\wamp\www\boobloom\site\class.Utility.inc.php on line 25
   Registration Successful.
```

This is the function I am using in my registration form:

```
if(mysql_query($insert_query)){
    Utility::sendRegConfirmEmail(mysql_insert_id());
    echo $message = "Registration Successful.";
}else{
    echo $message = "Registration not Successful.";
}
```

and:

```
 static function sendRegConfirmEmail($id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $to = $row['email'];
            $confirmationcode = $row['confirmation_code'];
    $tVar = time();
    $confirmLink = HTTP_PATH.'registrationConfirm/'.md5($tVar).'/'.$to.'/'.$confirmationcode.'/'.md5($to);
    // to fetch the email template
    $queryET = "SELECT * FROM emailtemplates WHERE type = 'registration_confirmation'";
    $resultET = mysql_query($queryET) or die(mysql_error());
    $rowET  = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultET);
    $subject = $rowET['subject'];
    $toRepArray   = array('[!Name!]','[!email!]','[!PASSWORD!]','[!activation_code!]','[!Link!]');
    $fromRepArray = array($to,$to,$row['password'],$confirmationcode,$confirmLink);
    $message = str_replace($toRepArray,$fromRepArray,$rowET['message']);
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: boobloom.com <".SITE_MAIL.">\r\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

Comment: Contact your server administrator regarding this type of problem

Comment: omnath, it seems you did not read the error message as this tells you what the problem is and it has nothing to do with a user email ID. Secondly you didn't tell us the file where the code is in as the error specifies class.Utility.inc.php but we could be looking at any code that is unrelated for all we know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is from your smtp setup and not your code. You should verify that your smtp is properly set up.

Try using

```
echo ini_get("SMTP");
echo ini_get("smtp_port");
```

To get your SMTP details.
Check your php.ini

It should be in this kinda format

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

Comment: ya i got the same as u write...localhost25

Comment: now,I'm using my site admin panel.registration successful message is come.any error and warning's are not show,but emails are not going on the addresses...

Comment: @omnath Check in your junk folder in your mail!